# integrating libGDX Game with google play games Leaderboards wit help of android basic examples

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I have a game written in LibGDX and i want to integrate google play services leaderboards in it . I have read code of the basic samples provided by google for implementing leader boards in below repository

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

and TypeANumber is a project where leaderboards are implemented . MainActivity in TypeANumber extends a class FragmentActivity which is provided by google and needs to be extended in my Game and similarly libGDX Game class also extends AndroidApplication Class which needs to be extended for libGDX Framework .

Now Java doesn't  support multiple inheritance , I need your help on how to extend both these classes . I have implemented all other required interfaces so far .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those fragments are just states of game actually. 
You don't have to extend fragments.

Just add googleplaygamesservices methods to androidlauncher that implements an interface from core directory. 
So you can create an instance of this interface in core and able to call gameservices methods from actual game codes. 
This is my interface named PlayServices inside core.

```
public interface PlayServices
{
public void signIn();
public void signOut();
public void rateGame();
public void unlockAchievement(String str);
public void submitScore(int highScore);
public void submitLevel(int highLevel);
public void showAchievement();
public void showScore();
public void showLevel();
public boolean isSignedIn();
public void showBannerAd();
public void hideBannerAd();
public void showInterstitialAd (Runnable then);
public void showRewardedVideo();
public boolean isRewardEarned();
}
```

As you can see i don't just use leaderboard but several services like all types of ads, achievements etc.

Here is opensource of my game.Google Play services may be bit old version but logic is same.

https://github.com/ahmetdenizyilmaz/connect

Game link if you wanted to see those in action

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ady.connect

Comment: Hi @Denis Thanks for your post it was helpful but my question was how to use android basic samples , in your repo you are using BaseGameUtils , however in androidbasicSamples BaseGameUtils are not present

Comment: I don't know new system yet. I will edit when i figure out.

Comment: thanks for response . I have usee baseUtils and implemented code as per your open source , i mean using my leaderboard and app id . But when it try to login to google play services but throws an error that cant sign in . I have checked documentation thrice but still giving login error . Do you have any idea or experience on the same

Comment: @Denis , I am able to log in to play games services and your open source helped me a lot in understanding it .  I still need to figure out how to do it using the android basic samples , but thanks for your work and your code which had BaseUtils .

Comment: @Denis ,your answer really helped  , I have written a details tut on this here https://www.versionpb.com/tutorials/step-step-tutorials-libgdx-basic-setup-libgdx/implementing-google-play-services-leaderboards-in-libgdx/